# How to check whether a key is pressed physically (not logically)?

Tags: c++, windows, keyboard, keyboard-events

While the 'w' key is physically pressed, another program presses and releases it in a loop.
"if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x57) & 0x8000)" registers these presses and releases.
How to check the real physical state of the 'w' key?

Comment: What do you mean by "another program presses and releases it in a loop" please?  Do you mean via `SendInput` or similar?

Comment: Yes, AutoHotKey "Send, {w Up}" and "Send, {w Down}"

Comment: In that case you'll need to install a [low level keyboard hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexw).  Specifically, you want `WH_KEYBOARD_LL`, then see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644985(v=vs.85)) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-kbdllhookstruct).  You'll see that there's a flag there to tell you if the keystroke was 'injected', and that's the one you want.  You process will likely need to run elevated to catch them all.

Answer (score 0):

A physical keyboard sends messages just like functions such as SendInput and it is not possible to tell the difference between them.

Comment: This answer is not quite correct. As has meanwhile been pointed out in one of the comments to the question, it is possible using a low-level keyboard hook to determine whether the input was injected.

Comment: I was actually going to add that fact but that still only receives messages so it is still impossible to determine the state of a key till it is pressed or released.